# How to write more elegant mapping of these conditions?

Tags: c#

I have 40 datasets, but when user click some of them I need to map their ID's to another dataset:

```
 public async Task<PagedResult<DataSetUpdateViewModel>> Handle(GetDataSetUpdateByDataSetIdQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    { //this I need to refactor
     if(request.ID==29)
        {
            request.ID = 28;
            request.DeleteAble = true;
        }
      if(request.ID==30)
        { request.ID=31;
          request.DeleteAble = true;
        }
      if(request.ID==32)
        { request.ID=31;
          request.DeleteAble = true;
        }
      if(request.ID==33)
        { request.ID=31;
          request.DeleteAble = true;
        }
        //if request.ID is not 29,30,32 or 33, then it should be pass as it is
        var datasetUpdates = _context.DatasetUpdates
        .Where(c => request.ID > 0 && c.DatasetId == request.ID)
        .ProjectTo<DataSetUpdateViewModel>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider,new { isDeleteAble = request.DeleteAble });
         

        PagedResult<DataSetUpdateViewModel> result = new PagedResult<DataSetUpdateViewModel>();
        result = await datasetUpdates.DynamicOrderBy("UpdateDate", "DESC")
                        .GetPagedAsync(request.PageNumber, request.PageSize, cancellationToken);
        return result;

    }
```

My `GetDataSetUpdateByDataSetIdQuery` looks like

```
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public bool DeleteAble { get; set; }
```

I know I can assign Enums to these numbers, but it still does not solve a lot of `if` conditions

Comment: @Qwerty 31, in 3 datasets I use data from 31 and then manipulate them.

Comment: since expected mapping is not in a series so better to use dictionary as @Mathias suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a simple `Dictionary<int, int>`:

```
internal static Dictionary<int, int> _queryMapping = new Dictionary<int, int>
{
    {29, 28},
    {30, 31},
    {32, 31},
    {33, 31}
}

// ...

public async Task<PagedResult<DataSetUpdateViewModel>> Handle(GetDataSetUpdateByDataSetIdQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if(_queryMapping.ContainsKey(request.ID)){
        request.ID = _queryMapping[request.ID];
        request.DeleteAble = true;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Is it good idea to make new static class just with this dictionary, so I can use this setup in whole project?

Comment: @Lube if you're only using the mapping from this particular class then I'd just attach it as a static property of said class, no need to define a static class just to own this.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe not as nice, but I like it:

```
public static class Ex
{
    public static Func<K, V> Map<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V> source, Func<K, V> @default)
        => key => (key == null || !source.ContainsKey(key)) ? @default(key) : source[key];
}
```

Then you do:

```
var request = new Request() { ID = 29 };

var map = new Dictionary<int, (int, bool)>
{
    {29, (28, true)},
    {30, (31, true)},
    {32, (31, true)},
    {33, (31, true)}
}.Map(k => (k, false));

(request.ID, request.DeleteAble) = map(request.ID);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a Datatable for lookup :

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("old id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("new id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("deletable", typeof(Boolean));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 29, 28, true });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 30, 31, true });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 32, 31, true });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 33, 31, true });

            DataRow searchResults = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("old id") == 32).FirstOrDefault();

            int newId = searchResults.Field<int>("new id");
```